# Android - ExtractEditText class

Tags: android, android-edittext, textview

Here is the doc [Android doc on extractEditText](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/inputmethodservice/ExtractEditText.html)

Can someone tell me its purpose ? Obviously i've read the doc in the link i provided but im still not clear what it does or for that matter what is an extract in reference to a EditText ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the specialization of the EditText for when the device is in landscape mode.  If you're developing an app, you don't need to worry about it.  If you're developing an InputMethod, then you can use it.